# Помогите исправить ошибку: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, sqlite

#### Ошибка:

> elif message.text == '/page_{0}'.format(row[0]):
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment

#### Код:

```
  ...

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def game(message):
    if message.text == 'Hello':
        db_worker = SQLighter(config.database_name)
        user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
        row = db_worker.select_single(l[db_worker.read_page(user_id)[2]])
        

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row[0], row[1] + '/page' + str(row[0])
        db_worker.close()

     elif message.text == '/page{0}'.format(row[0]): 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row[0])

...
```

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка говорит о том, что на момент проверки переменная `row` у вас еще не инициализирована. Она у вас инициализируется в другой ветке `if` выше. Я предполагаю, что нужно вынести часть кода из первой ветки `if` до самого `if`, будет что-то вроде этого:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def game(message):
    db_worker = SQLighter(config.database_name)
    user_id = int(message.from_user.id)
    row = db_worker.select_single(l[db_worker.read_page(user_id)[2]])
    db_worker.close()

    if message.text == 'Hello':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row[0], row[1] + '/page' + str(row[0])
    elif message.text == '/page{0}'.format(row[0]): 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, row[0])
```

Хотя, могу ошибаться, т.к. не знаю логики работы вашей программы.

Comment: данной вариант не подходит, возможно ли как-то реализовать по другому? подключения к база должно быть внутри первого if

Comment: @Surfer, это вам должно быть виднее. `row` у вас заполняется по запросу из базы, который находится в первом `if`. Если первое условие не выполняется, то `row` не заполняется, и на втором условии происходит ошибка. Отсюда напрашивается вывод - запрос нужно выносить до `if`. Явных причин, почему подключение к базе и запрос должны быть именно в первом ифе, я не вижу. Если они есть, распишите их.

Answer (score 1):

У вас в сообщении об ошибке написано, что переменная `var` еще не назначена, т.е. ей нужно присвоить какое-либо значение, например `row='spam'`, перед условным выражение `if`