# Вопрос, multiprocessing q.put_nowait() и q.get_nowait()

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, multiprocessing

Хелп, Вот код:

```
def ScreenCapture(q):
    while True:
        img = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        tt1 = t1.detectMultiScale(img, aiscale, aineigh)
        q.put_nowait(tt1)
        q.join()

def Detect(q):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            tt1 = q.get_nowait()
            for (x,y,w,h) in tt1:
                m = int(x + w / 2 + sw)
                n = int(y + h / 2 + sh)
            q.put_nowait(m)
    q.join() 
def test(q):
    if not q.empty():
        m = q.get_nowait()
        print(m)
if __name__=="__main__":
    q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=ScreenCapture, args=(q, ))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=Detect, args=(q, ))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(q, ))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
```

Не получается взять переменные n и m даже если вручную их указываю

Comment: `m = 0` перед циклом.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите исправить ошибку: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521125/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-row-referenced-be)

Comment: @вася изменил, не выдаёт ошибку - но теперь я не могу вытащить переменную

Comment: @userpy что значит *не могу вытащить переменную*?

Comment: @вася командой q.put_nowait(m) я передал переменную и командой m = q.get_nowait() получил её, но когда вывожу через print - ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так наверное и в функции `test` надо сделать цикл:

```
def test(q):
    while True:
        if not q.empty():
            m = q.get_nowait()
            print(m)
```

Иначе поскольку очередь вначале пуста ничего не произойдёт и функция просто закончится.
Ещё непонятно, как вы собираетесь из циклов выходить вообще. И в одной функции у вас `q.join()` внутри цикла, а в другой снаружи. Вы уж определитесь как правильно.