# Код не видит переменные Python

Tags: python

Пишу Телеграм бота на AIOGram и не понимаю почему получаю ошибку:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'number_of_skins_with_rare_stickers' referenced before assignment
```

Вот код:

```
...
count_of_skins_passed = 0
time_of_passage_of_skins = 0
number_of_skins_with_rare_stickers = 0
number_of_skins_with_rare_floats = 0
number_of_skins_with_rare_patterns = 0
...
def posting(table_name):
    ...
    if rare_pattern != 0:
        number_of_skins_with_rare_patterns += 1
    else:
        pass
    ...

async def main(message: Message, as_html = True):
    ...
    with open(f'report.txt', 'w') as report_file:
        report_file.write(f'Результат парсинга от {datetime.datetime.now()}:')
        report_file.write(f'Количество пройденных скинов: {count_of_skins_passed}')
        report_file.write(f'Общее время: {time_of_passage_of_skins}')
        ...
```

Большую часть скрипта не добавлял, но думаю и так понятно основная структура. Переменные оглашены вне функций, в одной из функций они изменяются, а в другой - записываются в файл. Проверил через `print(globals())` - все переменные там есть. Вопрос в том, почему скрипт их не видит.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите исправить ошибку: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/521125/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-row-referenced-be)

Comment: @splash58 в вопросе, который вы прикрепили совсем другая ситуация. У меня переменные оглашены вне функции

Comment: попробуйте изучить области видимости получше https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/oblasti-vidimosti-peremennyh-v-python

Comment: ох! про это там и написано, что нельзя изменять переменную, объявленную вне функции. можно только через глобал

Answer (score 1):

Вам и правда стоит разобраться с тем, как работают области видмости. Когда вы пишите:

*(Python 3.9)*

```
l = []
def a(l: list[int]):
  l.append(1)
a(l) 
print(l) # [1]
```

В функцию a попадает ссылка на list. Мы обращаемся к методу по этой ссылке.

Когда пишем:
*(Python 3.9)*

```
l = []
def a(l: list[int]):
  l = [1]
a(l)
print(l) # []
```

мы создаем НОВЫЙ list l в локальной области видимости функции a. Глобальная переменная l НЕ МЕНЯЕТСЯ !!!

### Решение

Что бы это исправить вы можете создать некоторую струтуру

```
class Counter:
  def __init__(self):
     self.number_of_skins_with_rare_patterns = 0
  def register_rare_patern(smth):
    # do smth
    self.number_of_skins_with_rare_patterns += 1
```

Дальше:

```
counter = Counter()
```

И в функции post():

```
def posting(table_name, counter):
    ...
    if rare_pattern != 0:
        counter.register_rare_patern()
    else:
        pass
    ...
```

### Другое, не очень правильное решение проблемы

В принципе вы можете явно указать что такая - то переменная - глобальная:

```
def post():
    global var
```

Однако такая реализация может таить в себе много подводных камней.